# How to recover my ubuntu (start ubuntu from a raw disk partition)

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, grub

I have windows 8 PC. 931 GB HD (641 windows and 200 gb for ubuntu.)
windows and ubuntu in different drives.
Ubuntu partition is a raw type of disk drive while windows is a ntfs.

when I needed to start ubuntu, I would go into the advance startup options -> boot from disk drive -> there would be 2 partitions, when I select one of them I would get that ubuntu window something like this: 
**https://www.dropbox.com/s/kjad5psde6dc2rg/stack.jpg?dl=0**

Now,
I refresh my windows 8 PC. It takes quite a long time and uninstalls a lot of softwares from my PC.
It looks like it also uninstalled some software (grub or something ) responsible for booting of ubunut. so Now when ever I go to my advance startup options I do not see the disk drive partition from which used to start ubuntu.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/odxm5r7ix4ffq8l/stack1.PNG?dl=0

In windows I can not access my raw drive in which ubuntu was installed.

I am adding links to images as I do not have privileges to add image.

Thanks